# Method getting called multiple times

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, concurrency, mpmovieplayer

I am using `MPMoviePlayer` in my project. I have registered for the movie player finish notifications and it is working good. I am displaying an error alert whenever a notification is received for movie player error. But the problem is that the error alert displays multiple times. It happens because more than one notifications are received for same error and that too at the same time. I have tried using boolean variables to control the alert display but since the notifications are received at the same time, it is not working. What approach should I apply, please suggest.
My code for notification method:

```
MPMovieFinishReason reason = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];
NSError *errorMsg = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"error"];
NSString *errmsg = [errorMsg localizedDescription];
if (reason == 1 && !errorReceived){
    NSError *errorMsg = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"error"];
    NSString *errmsg = [errorMsg localizedDescription];
    [self showErrorAlert];
}
```

For registering notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter* center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.player];
```

for  removing observer, in `viewWillDisappear`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Have you verified you are only registering for the notification once? Do you unregister the notification when appropriate?

Comment: How did you register the notification? And is there a chance that this notification is registered several times? It is possible also that you forgot to remove some observers from the notification after it was triggered.

Comment: Yes, I have registered it once and I have also unregistered it.

Comment: Please show the code for registration and unregistration.

Comment: you tried to remove notification when you got notification??

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya No, the observer is removed in viewdiddisappear. And the problem is not with adding and removing notification.

Comment: plz try once you are get notfication in your method moviePlayerDidFinish: in that remove that notification

Comment: for Ex: add notification   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)  
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:_moviePlayer]; and Remove that Like in moviePlayBackDidFinish: method like  MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

Comment: @user3308898 you have to add the method where you add this observer, we already saw that the addObserver is correct, but we need to see where you are doing it, and how. So, show us the full method where you add your observer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the observer once you get the error

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

and add the observer once you click to play .